# Groovy Script to convert String to Integer values in the Json

Tags: groovy

I have a json in which i need to convert the certain strings into integer value, that is remove the double quotes , Below is input json

```
{
  "DELVRY07": {
    "IDOC": {
      "@BEGIN": "1",
      "EDI_DC40": {
        "@SEGMENT": "1",  
      },
      "E1EDL20": {
        "@SEGMENT": "1"
        "E1EDL21": {
          "@SEGMENT": "1"
        },
        "E1ADRM1": [
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
          }
        ],
        "E1EDT13": [
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
            "QUALF": "006",
            "NTANF": "20230711",
            "ISDD": "20230711"
          },
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
            "QUALF": "003",
            "NTANF": "20230711"
          }
        ]
}}}}
```

and i need to convert the NATANF & ISDD field values  into integer values that is to remove quotes .My outout json needs to be as below

```
{
  "DELVRY07": {
    "IDOC": {
      "@BEGIN": "1",
      "EDI_DC40": {
        "@SEGMENT": "1",  
      },
      "E1EDL20": {
        "@SEGMENT": "1"
        "E1EDL21": {
          "@SEGMENT": "1"
        },
        "E1ADRM1": [
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
          }
        ],
        "E1EDT13": [
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
            "QUALF": "006",
            "NTANF": 20230711,
            "ISDD": 20230711
          },
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
            "QUALF": "003",
            "NTANF": 20230711
          }
        ]
}}}}
```

I am using below script but it does not work

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def list = jsonSlurper.parseText(body)
    list['NTANF'] = Integer.parseInt(list['NTANF'])
list['ISDD'] = Integer.parseInt(list['ISDD'])
    def jsonOP = JsonOutput.toJson(list)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: if you convert ALL Strings to Integers, would it be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the quotes around numeric values in the original json String:

```
import groovy.json.*
    
String body = '''\
{
  "DELVRY07": {
    "IDOC": {
      "@BEGIN": "1",
      "EDI_DC40": {
        "@SEGMENT": "1",  
      },
      "E1EDL20": {
        "@SEGMENT": "1",
        "E1EDL21": {
          "@SEGMENT": "1"
        },
        "E1ADRM1": [
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
          }
        ],
        "E1EDT13": [
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
            "QUALF": "006",
            "NTANF": "20230711",
            "ISDD": "20230711"
          },
          {
            "@SEGMENT": "1",
            "QUALF": "003",
            "NTANF": "20230711"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}'''

body = body.replaceAll( /"([1-9]\d+)"/, '$1' )

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText body

assert Integer == json.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[ 0 ].NTANF.getClass()
assert String == json.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[ 0 ].QUALF.getClass()
assert Integer == json.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[ 0 ].ISDD.getClass()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to reach to specific node and then change the value. For example,

```
  list.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[0].NTANF = Integer.parseInt(list.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[0].NTANF)
  list.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[1].NTANF = Integer.parseInt(list.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[1].NTANF)
  list.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[0].ISDD = Integer.parseInt(list.DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDT13[0].ISDD)
```